# How can I compress images in PowerPoint via C#?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, powerpoint

I am using C# to generate a bunch of SSRS Reports offscreen, and then take the created image(s) for each report and paste them into a PowerPoint presentation, effectively collating all the reports together into one pack.  While this works fine, it results in a filesize of 23mb, for only a 26 page presentation. (I undersand that using a high dpi has partly resulted in this monster number, but has proved necessary to create an image of the required clarity).

When I save this presentation manually within PowerPoint however, the file size reduces to approximately 13mb.  (This is with the compress pictures option Target output set to 96dpi).  Is there a way I can command Powerpoint to save all the images at a lower resolution from within my code so the generated file is smaller?

(Currently, throughout my process, the file is being saved when called by the SlidePart `.Save()` command only.)

### Further information

I am generating the images off-screen at 600dpi.  When a lower resolution is used, the image quality drops off when printing and random fuzzy artefacts start appearing between the letters (I assume due to some form of anti-aliasing)

This results in images being created, that when pasted into PowerPoint, are a huge 121cm x 171cm which are scaled at 16%.  However, once I view this presentation in PowerPoint, and subsequently save it, it reduces the image size down to the slide size at 100% scale, with no loss of quality.

I suppose the question is, how can I instruct my program to perform this resizing transformation?  The code I’m using is as follows

```
private void ReplaceSlideImage(SlidePart slidePart, byte[] imageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, ImagePartType imageType)
{
  // The ratio of the image size to the slide size
  // Set to 1.0 to make the image fill the slide, or < 1.0 to leave a border
  const double IMAGE_SCALE_FACTOR = 1.0;

  Slide theSlide = slidePart.Slide;
  double slideAspectRatio = 0.0;
  double imageAspectRatio = 0.0;

  System.IO.MemoryStream imageStream = null;

  // Look for the first embedded image on the slide.
  Drawing.Blip blip = theSlide.Descendants<Drawing.Blip>().FirstOrDefault();

  if (blip != null)
  {
    // Add the new image part.
    ImagePart newImagePart = slidePart.AddImagePart(imageType);

    imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
    newImagePart.FeedData(imageStream);
    blip.Embed = slidePart.GetIdOfPart(newImagePart);

    // Scale the image to fit the slide
    SlideSize slideSize = m_file.PresentationPart.Presentation.Descendants<SlideSize>().First();
    Transform2D imageTransform = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<Transform2D>().First();

    slideAspectRatio = (double)slideSize.Cx / (double)slideSize.Cy;
    imageAspectRatio = (double)imageWidth / (double)imageHeight;

    if (imageAspectRatio > slideAspectRatio)
    {
      imageTransform.Extents.Cx = (Int64)(slideSize.Cx * IMAGE_SCALE_FACTOR);
      imageTransform.Extents.Cy = (Int64)(slideSize.Cx * IMAGE_SCALE_FACTOR / imageAspectRatio);
    }
    else
    {
      imageTransform.Extents.Cy = (Int64)(slideSize.Cy * IMAGE_SCALE_FACTOR);
      imageTransform.Extents.Cx = (Int64)(slideSize.Cy * IMAGE_SCALE_FACTOR * imageAspectRatio);
    }

    // Recentre the image to the middle of the slide 
    imageTransform.Offset.X = (slideSize.Cx / 2) - (imageTransform.Extents.Cx / 2);
    imageTransform.Offset.Y = (slideSize.Cy / 2) - (imageTransform.Extents.Cy / 2);

    theSlide.Save();

    // Dispose of the image stream
    imageStream.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have Pie.  Eat Pie.  Choose one.  ;-)

You're saying you need high DPI images to preserve quality.
Then you're asking how to get PowerPoint to reduce the DPI.

It's not clear from your question, but sounds as though you might have some control over the initial resolution of the images.  If that's so, why not generate them at the desired DPI before inserting them into PowerPoint?

If that's not practical, you can set a few registry entries that override PowerPoint's default compression.  Note that you have to make the reg changes before launching PowerPoint, otherwise they'll have no effect.

This explains how to turn default compression on/off:
PowerPoint 2007 and 2010 make pictures blurry, loses GIF animation
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00862_PowerPoint_2007_and_2010_make_pictures_blurry-_loses_GIF_animation.htm

Compression DPI and whether or not to discard image data are stored per-presentation.  Crack a PPTX open and look at presProps.xml in the ppt folder within the PPTX/ZIP file.

Comment: The default compression is currently turned on, but isn't applied to the presentation until the file is saved manually by the user.  I'm trying to achieve this save and compression programatically.  I've added more information to my original question if that makes things clearer... Thanks

Comment: "When a lower resolution is used, the image quality drops off when printing and random fuzzy artefacts start appearing between the letters " What format are you using for the images originally?  It sounds like JPG at a fairly high compression rate, which results in exactly the kind of artifacting that you describe.  Try PNG at the resolution you actually want in the resulting PPT ... for a typical PPT, 10x7.5" * 96dpi.  As far as I can see, there's no properties/methods dealing with compression exposed via the OM.